# Same Image Preview getting displayed for all attachments

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, visualforce-component, attachment

I am trying to display respective attachment preview on a VF Page, but if you can see below picture of my VF page, same image is getting displayed for all attachments, not sure where i'm going wrong[image: MY VF PAGE DISPLAY]

Below is the respective coding part which i have used for this functionality

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="DelAttachments_Img_Controller" >
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Select the Attachments you want to Delete: " description="You can delete more than one attachments from the list below"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="DoSelection" action="{!selectAttachment}"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton Value="Delete"  action="{!AddAttachments}" immediate="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton Value="Cancel" action="{!GoBack_toRequest}" immediate="true" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAllAtach}" var="atch" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Select">
            <apex:inputCheckbox immediate="true" value="{!atch.Selected}" onclick="DoSelection()" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!atch.attachobj.Name}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!atch.attachobj.ContentType}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Size" value="{!atch.at_size}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Date Created" >
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date, MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" >
                <apex:param value="{!atch.at_createDate}" />
            </apex:outputText>

            <apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;"></apex:image>  
        </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class DelAttachments_Img_Controller {
public Id CaseId;
public selectedAttachments[] lstAllAtach {get; set;}
Public Map<Id,selectedAttachments> SelectedResultMap {get;set;}
list<Attachment> toBeDeleted {get;set;}
public String imageURL{get;set;}

public class selectedAttachments { 
    public Attachment attachobj{get; set;}
    public Boolean Selected {get;set;}
    public String at_size {get; set;}
    public DateTime at_createDate {get; set;}


}



public DelAttachments_Img_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    SelectedResultMap = new Map<Id,selectedAttachments>();
    CaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseID');
    if(CaseId != NULL)
    {
        lstAllAtach = new list<selectedAttachments>();
        List<Attachment> relatedAttachments = [SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, BodyLength, CreatedDate FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId =: CaseId];
        if(!relatedAttachments.isEmpty() && relatedAttachments != null) {
            for (Attachment a : relatedAttachments) {
                selectedAttachments oneAtch = new selectedAttachments();
                oneAtch.Selected = FALSE;
                oneAtch.attachobj = a;
                oneAtch.at_createDate = a.CreatedDate + offset;
                oneAtch.at_size = (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024 >=1024.0)? (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024).setScale(2)+' MB' : (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024).setScale(2)+' KB';
                lstAllAtach.add(oneAtch);
                imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
                 if(relatedAttachments.size()>0)
                  {
                      imageURL=imageURL+relatedAttachments[0].id;
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single `imageURL`, and its not part of the list of attachments

try

```
<apex:image url="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + atch.attachobj.Id}" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;"></apex:image>
```

and get rid of the imageURL declaration and also

```
imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
if(relatedAttachments.size()>0)
{
    imageURL=imageURL+relatedAttachments[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio Alcocer, this worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `imageURL` property is the same for all the records. You have to do the following:

a) Update your custom class to have the imageURL in

```
public class selectedAttachments { 
    public Attachment attachobj{get; set;}
    public Boolean Selected {get;set;}
    public String at_size {get; set;}
    public DateTime at_createDate {get; set;}
    public String imageURL{get;set;}
}
```

b) Update your apex so it populates properly

Remove

```
imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
if(relatedAttachments.size()>0)
{
    imageURL=imageURL+relatedAttachments[0].id;
}
```

and instead put

```
oneAtch.imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + a.id;
```

c) update your VF page to pull from the class

```
<apex:image url="{!atch.imageURL}" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;"></apex:image>
```

Comment: Point b, shouldn't it be `oneAtch.imageURL=imageURL+ a.id`?

Comment: I don’t think so. I’m copying the OP’s code and it seems to work for one image.

Comment: You have added imageUrl as a member of the wrapper class but it was still assigned with the first Id of the list. I think that would still display the same image for all the attachments.

Comment: Well, so it is. Good catch