# Create select all checkbox such that if select all is done then all attachments must get selected

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, visualforce-component, delete

Below is my VF Page and i need to create select all checkbox such that if select all is done then all attachments must get selected and then user can delete them at a go.[image]

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="DelAttachments_Img_Controller" >
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Select the Attachments you want to Delete: " description="You can delete more than one attachments from the list below"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="DoSelection" action="{!selectAttachment}"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton Value="Delete"  action="{!AddAttachments}" />
        <apex:commandButton Value="Cancel" action="{!GoBack_toRequest}" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAllAtach}" var="atch" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Select">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!atch.Selected}" immediate="true" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!atch.attachobj.Name}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Image Preview" > 
         <apex:image url="{!imageURL + atch.attachobj.Id}" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" alt="Not an image file"></apex:image>
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!atch.attachobj.ContentType}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Size" value="{!atch.at_size}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Date Created" >
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date, MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" >
                <apex:param value="{!atch.at_createDate}" />
            </apex:outputText>



        </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class DelAttachments_Img_Controller {
public Id CaseId;
public selectedAttachments[] lstAllAtach {get; set;}
Public Map<Id,selectedAttachments> SelectedResultMap {get;set;}
list<Attachment> toBeDeleted {get;set;}
public String imageURL{get;set;}

public class selectedAttachments { 
    public Attachment attachobj{get; set;}
    public Boolean Selected {get;set;}
    public String at_size {get; set;}
    public DateTime at_createDate {get; set;}
}



public DelAttachments_Img_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    SelectedResultMap = new Map<Id,selectedAttachments>();
    imageURL = Label.ImageURL;
    system.debug('imageURL: '+imageURL);
    CaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseID');
    if(CaseId != NULL)
    {
        lstAllAtach = new list<selectedAttachments>();
        List<Attachment> relatedAttachments = [SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, BodyLength, CreatedDate FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId =: CaseId];
        if(!relatedAttachments.isEmpty() && relatedAttachments != null) {
            for (Attachment a : relatedAttachments) {
                selectedAttachments oneAtch = new selectedAttachments();
                oneAtch.Selected = FALSE;
                oneAtch.attachobj = a;
                oneAtch.at_createDate = a.CreatedDate + offset;
                oneAtch.at_size = (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024 >=1024.0)? (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024).setScale(2)+' MB' : (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024).setScale(2)+' KB';
                lstAllAtach.add(oneAtch);
            }
        }
    }
}
public Double offset {
    get {
        TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
        return tz.getOffset(DateTime.now()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24.0);
    }   
}

public Void selectAttachment(){
    for(selectedAttachments tempObj:lstAllAtach){
        if(tempObj != null){
            System.debug(' tempobj selected value '+ tempobj.selected);
            if(tempObj.selected){
                SelectedResultMap.put(tempObj.attachobj.Id, tempObj);
                System.debug('SelectedResultMap >>>>>'+SelectedResultMap);

            }
        }
        else{
            if(SelectedResultMap.get(tempObj.attachobj.Id) != null){
                SelectedResultMap.remove(tempObj.attachobj.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}



public PageReference AddAttachments() { 

    toBeDeleted = new List<Attachment>();
    for(Id AttID :  SelectedResultMap.keySet())
    {
        if(AttID != null)
        {
            selectedAttachments delAttch = SelectedResultMap.get(AttID);
            Attachment attch = delAttch.attachobj;
            toBeDeleted.add(attch);
            SelectedResultMap.remove(AttID);
        }
    }
    if(toBeDeleted != null)
    {
        delete toBeDeleted;
    }

    PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/apex/DelAttachments_Img?CaseID='+CaseId);
    pageref.setRedirect(true);
    return pageref; 
}
public boolean checkIfSelected(selectedAttachments SCO){
    boolean rtnValue = false;
    if(SelectedResultMap.get(SCO.attachobj.id) != null){
        rtnValue = true;
    }
    return rtnValue;
}
public PageReference GoBack_toRequest() { 
    PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/'+CaseID);
    pageref.setRedirect(true);
    return pageref;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us *what you've tried* and *where you are stuck*.

Comment: Please use the Contact link at the bottom of every page to have your [duplicate accounts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306817/same-image-preview-getting-displayed-for-all-attachments) merged.